# Cisco snmp-server single user for multiple snmp versions

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-commands, snmp

Attempting to maintain SNMP v2c compatibility while implementing SNMP v3 on cisco switch 5506cx.

Would a user that was previously used for v2c see issues with v2c if it is added to a v3 group?

For instance:

```
snmp-server group myGroupName v2c
snmp-server user myUserName
snmp-server groupMyAuthPrivGroup v3 priv
snmp-server user myUserName groupMyAuthPrivGroup v3 auth..etc.
```

Would v2c have a problem with this user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be part of a group with a higher priority. If you set a higher priority then set the lower one, you may face some errors like `AUTHORIZATION_ERROR` or `unknownUserName` which is the result of bad configuration.

As a result, it would be safe if you gain access to a user.

---

Check this link out to understand levels and priorities:

[SNMP Version 3 Security Levels](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/snmp/configuration/xe-3se/3850/snmp-xe-3se-3850-book/nm-snmp-snmpv3.html#GUID-DCB20ADF-1F8E-434B-AE97-54802879F34F)

Comment: Thanks for the input! Going to move ahead by creating a separate user for snmp v3.